# Odd VHDL Syntax error in a 2-to-1 mux

Tags: vhdl

So I have this code for the dataflow of a 2-to-1 mux, and it's returning an odd syntax error that I can't figure out what is causing it. The error is at the semicolon of the indicated line.

```
entity TwotoOne is
PORT 
(
  w0, w1  : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s       : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 DOWNTO 0);
  f       : OUT STD_LOGIC
);

end TwotoOne;

architecture Dataflow of TwotoOne is
BEGIN

  WITH s SELECT
  f <= ((not s) and w0) or (s and w1); -- Error here

END Dataflow ;
```

Comment: One issue in addition to  the emboldened line not meeting the syntax for a selected signal assignment (use a regular signal assignment). `s` is declared as an array value selecting between two choices combinatorially. It should a scalar type (e.g. std_logic).  It's selecting between `w0` or `w1`, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xZO7k.jpg). Please make your question an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're missing a context clause in addition to providing the error, consider formatting the VHDL as code. The `not` operator is higher priority, parentheses not needed for `not s`.

Answer (score 0):

- Your two-input multiplexer has a 2-bit selection input, `s`; it need only be a single bit.
- You cannot perform an `and` of a vector with a single bit.
- Your `with` statement is completely invalid.

If you simply delete the `with` line, and make `s` an `std_logic`, I suspect your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are planning to write 4-to-1 mux, `s` is only `1 bit`

```
entity TwotoOne is
PORT 
(
  w0, w1, s  : IN STD_LOGIC;
  f       : OUT STD_LOGIC
);

end TwotoOne;

architecture Dataflow of TwotoOne is
BEGIN

  f <= ((not s) and w0) or (s and w1); 

END Dataflow ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The with/select statement is incomplete which causes the error.
You can either completely remove the `WITH s SELECT` line, or replace all lines in the body of your entity with

```
with s select f <=
    w0 when '0',
    w1 when others;
```